# Is there someone have success in scraping from Amazon using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to make a web scraper of Amazon.

But, It looks like that everydata is None type.

I found in google and there are many peoples who make a web scraper of Amazon.

Please, give me some advice to solve this Nonetype issue.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

amazon_dir = requests.get("https://www.amazon.es/s?k=docking+station&__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=34FO3BVVCJS4V&sprefix=docking%2Caps%2C302&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_1_7")
amazon_soup = BeautifulSoup(amazon_dir.text, "html.parser")
product_table = amazon_soup.find("div", {"class": "sg-col-inner"})
print(product_table)

products = product_table.find("div", {"class": "a-section"})
name = products.find("span", {"class": "a-size-base-plus"})
rating = products.find("span", {"class": "a-icon-alt"})
price = products.find("span", {"class": "a-price-whole"})
print(name, rating, price)
```

Thank you

Comment: check the response code firstly, try add a user agent! check if the site using JS or not.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I never do that process. But, I will find and try it. thanks

Comment: if `amazon.es` uses `JavaScript` then `requests` + `BeautifulSoup` will not work because they can't run `JavaScript`. I'm not sure but for some countries `Amazon` may use `JavaScript` and for others it may runs without `JavaScript`. Or maybe long time ago `Amazan` was running without `JavaScript` but now uses `JavaScript` - you should check how old are tutorials/posts on Internet.

Comment: code works for me if I use header `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0`

Comment: @furas Thank you very much. It is not for this case, But How can I know if the website is run with JavaScript? I'd like to know

Comment: you can turn off JavaScript in browser and reload page to see what you can get without JavaScript.. You can find this option in some settings or you may install some extension which add button to toolbar - i.e [extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/disable-javascript/)

Comment: Hi @SeowooJang -- you can randomize multiple user-agents. If you stick to one, it may work for a couple of requests but will eventually stop working. You may also consider using proxy rotation too as a layer. This article helps me with amazon scalable scraping. It suggests additional layer using scraperapi. https://medium.com/@scraperguy/this-could-be-the-answer-to-your-web-scraping-problems-66c88e775c42

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Portals may check header `User-Agent` to send different HTML for different browsers or devices and sometimes this can make problem to find elements on page.

But usually portals check this header to block scripts/bots.
For example `requests` sends `User-Agent: python-requests/2.26.0`.

If I use header `User-Agent` from real browser or at least shorter version `Mozilla/5.0` then code works.

---

There is other problem.

There is almost 70 elements `<div class="sg-col-inner" ...>` and table is as 3th element but `find()` gives only first element. You have to use `find_all()` and later use `[2]` to get 3th element.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
}    

url = "https://www.amazon.es/s?k=docking+station&__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=34FO3BVVCJS4V&sprefix=docking%2Caps%2C302&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_1_7"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text[:1000])
print('---')

amazon_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
all_divs = amazon_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "sg-col-inner"})

print('len(all_divs):', len(all_divs))
print('---')

products = all_divs[3].find("div", {"class": "a-section"})
name = products.find("span", {"class": "a-size-base-plus"})
rating = products.find("span", {"class": "a-icon-alt"})
price = products.find("span", {"class": "a-price-whole"})
print('name:', name.text)
print('rating:', rating.text)
print('price:', price.text)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version which display all products:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
}    

url = "https://www.amazon.es/s?k=docking+station&__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=34FO3BVVCJS4V&sprefix=docking%2Caps%2C302&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_1_7"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

#print(response.text[:1000])
#print('---')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

results = soup.find("div", {"class": "s-main-slot s-result-list s-search-results sg-row"})

all_products = results.find_all("div", {"class": "sg-col-inner"})
print('len(all_products):', len(all_products))
print('---')

for item in all_products:
    name = item.find("span", {"class": "a-size-base-plus"})
    rating = item.find("span", {"class": "a-icon-alt"})
    price = item.find("span", {"class": "a-price-whole"})
    if name:
        print('name:', name.text)
    if rating:
        print('rating:', rating.text)
    if price:
        print('price:', price.text)
    if name or rating or price:
        print('---')
```

---

**BTW:**

From time to time portals refresh code and HTML on servers - so if you find tutorial then check how old it is. Older tutorials may not work because portals could changed something in code.

Many modern pages start using JavaScript to add elements but `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`. And this may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`.